# Loadingoverlay in html with Javascript

Tags: html

I am trying to place an overlay and loading spinner to block user interaction till loading complete in html file.

With reference of the tutorial http://www.jqueryrain.com/?eKV1bCMa 
 trying to place a Whole page Overlay and Single element Overlay.
But it is not working.
Seeking help to get it done
Thank you
Given below is the code.`

```js
<script src="loadingoverlay.js"></script>
<script src="loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#firstdata").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("data2.html");
    });
  $("#driver").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
    });
});



 // Show full page Loading Overlay
 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#firstdata").click(function()
 {
 $.LoadingOverlay("show");

 // Hide it after 3 seconds
 setTimeout(function(){$.LoadingOverlay("hide");}, 3000);

}); 
});

// Show element Loading Overlay
 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#driver").click(function()
 {
 $("#element").LoadingOverlay("show");

 // Hide it after 3 seconds
 setTimeout(function(){$.LoadingOverlay("hide");}, 3000);

}); 
});
 
</script>
```

```html
<body>

<div id="element">
 <input type = "button" id = "firstdata" value = "External Content" /><br>
<br><br>
<input type = "button" id = "driver" value = "Load Data" />
<br><br><br><br>
</div>
<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
</body>
```

`

Comment: Did you add loadingoverlay.js file to your html file? It is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you must load jQuery **before** any other plugin, otherwise they won't work.
Then, there's no need for a full *and* a minified version of the same script, so your script loading becomes:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>
```

About the code itself, I don't know if it will work as expected, but for sure you don't need all those `$(document).ready` handlers and timers.
You can use only one and take advantage of the `complete` parameter of the `.load()` function. The whole script can be written as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#firstdata").click(function(){
        $.LoadingOverlay("show");
        $("#div1").load("data2.html", function(){
            $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
        });
    });

     $("#driver").click(function(){
        $("#element").LoadingOverlay("show");
        $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt", function(){
            $("#element").LoadingOverlay("hide");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Great..! Working smoothly .Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any additional jquery library for this. It can be achieved by simple piece of basic css and  jquery code. as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('ajax-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: none;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function showLoader(){
        //show loader onclcik of button
         $('.loader').css('display','block');
        setTimeout(function(){
            var changedText = 'Text changes';
            $('#div1').html(changedText);// enter text here to required changes
             $('.loader').css('display','none');
        }, 3000);    
}


</script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="loader"></div>

<div id="element">
<input type = "button"  value = "Load Data" onclick="showLoader();" />
</div>
<div ><h2 id="div1">Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
```

Note: you can download loader image from http://www.ajaxload.info/ for reference.

Hope this will help